# Dynamic select value

Tags: php, mysql

Example:

```
$user_input = $_POST['input'];
'SELECT '.$user_input.' FROM table_name'
```

So it's selecting a column in a database based on a secure (this example isn't secure obviously) value. Is this practical/allowable code?

Comment: Sorry it's supposed to be $user_input

Comment: this is very insecure code. for instance $user_input = '; delete from table_name ; #';

Comment: Somebody didn't read the 'this isn't secure obviously' part

Comment: @PRPGFerret I wouldn't worry about it. I *always* mention PDO and/or MySQLi, since I figure the more people that mention it the better. Also, I quite like Waqar's example. SQL injection in a column name doesn't show up in questions as often as other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you simply send a `string` to the DBMS (like MySQL). Because of this you can build any `string` you want and submit it to the DBMS.

You just have to make sure the resulting SQL query is valid. That means that e.g. the columns exist and that no invalid symbol appears.

Comment: right, I have a big if statement making sure the value is a valid one, and if true, query is sent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On it's face, this code is valid, assuming that `$user_input` must be a valid column name, which means that it must exist and must not contain any special characters, reserved words, etc. (unless they're escaped).

As you said, however, this code isn't secure, but as long as you plan to build the query securely and use PDO or MySQLi (no deprecated `mysql_*` functions...), you should be fine. If you need an example that doesn't use deprecated functions (including `mysql_real_escape_string`, which is also being deprecated) I'll provide one.

I know you stated that you know this code isn't secure, but here's another example if you're curious. As was discussed in the comments and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11874991/869912), this input:

```
$user_input = '; DELETE FROM table_name ; *';
'SELECT '.$user_input.' FROM table_name'
```

will delete the entire contents of the table `table_name`. Even though this code raises a syntax error, MySQL will continue to execute it, thus effectively truncating `table_name`.